# Silent install exe with logging enabled

Tags: command-line-arguments, installshield

I have been facing a really strange problem trying to automate the installation of NewForma.

Below is the line I'm using in a bat file:

```
"\\bdc\deployment$\NewForma\NewformaProjectCenterOffice64Setup.exe" /s /v"/qn /log \\bdc\deployment$\NewForma\IT tool\log.log" /v"/qn NPCS_LOCATION=ABC-NFM"
```

It works fine, but no log file is created.

I was wondering if it is a problem with the syntax.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those opening quotes are supposed to be right after /v?

Comment: @Karan According to [here](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm) it's supposed to be like that...

Comment: @MichaelFrank: Yes, seems that way.

Comment: It looked odd to me as well, so I had to find out!

Comment: Wonder why this was downvoted? Anyway, I countered that. Hadi: According to the page @MichaelFrank linked to, looks like the log path needs to be quoted separately since it contains spaces, so try `/v"/qn /log \"\\bdc\deployment$\NewForma\IT tool\log.log\""` and see if that works.

Comment: @MichaelFrank sorry there! I didn't see your answer! but yours is close to mine!, what I needed to do is create a log and automatically point the software to our in house newforma server! Yours would work but it will ask for server later at first initialization! but thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
"\\bdc\deployment$\NewForma\NewformaProjectCenterOffice64Setup.exe" /s /v"/log "\\bdc\deployment$\NewForma\IT tool\log.log" /qn NPCS_LOCATION=ABC-NFM"
```

by combining the log switch and the entry for the setup, it can be achieved!

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The reason it works is that your log location is now quoted correctly.